Which font does the Redragon K552 use?
Anyone know which font this is? Or perhaps a font similar to it.


The letter shapes are somewhat similar to S&L Gothic. It shares many of the same features, although it's not a stencil font.  It wouldn't take much to modify it. Designers often modify fonts to create custom designs, so this may not be a font you can just find somewhere and download. If it's an existing fornt which has been modified, they probably wouldn't be able to distribute it for copyright reasons.
An example: S&L Gothic top, modified below.


Thanks, this is really helpful!
